# Converting DataGrid value from int Id to string Description

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, ivalueconverter

I have a `DataGrid` with a column defined like below:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Events}" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Unit" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding UnitId}"/>
        ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The problem is: I am bound to a list of `Events` that only have a `UnitId` property. I don't want to display the `UnitId`. I'd like to display the `Description` of the Unit.My ViewModel contains an `IList<Unit>` that looks like the following:

```
public class Unit 
{
    public int UnitId {get;set;}
    public string Description { get;set;}
}
```

But the ViewModel is not the datacontext of the DataGrid, so I'd have to do some RelativeSource shenanigans.

So, for instance, if I had a Unit with a `UnitId` of 1 and a `Description` of "Upper Folder", I'd want the cell to display "Upper Folder"

I think I may be able to use an `IValueConverter` for something like this but am not sure if this is the easiest way to go about it.

Comment: Why do you have to bind to Id why not just bind to Description?

Comment: Does `Binding="{Binding Description}"` not satisfy your needs?

Comment: Ah, I updated my question to reflect the fact that the `DataGrid` data context is a list of `Events`, which only contain a property of `UnitId`. I need to look up the `UnitId` in a list of Unit objects I have in my ViewModel and display the `Description` base on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add a property of type 'Unit' to your `Event` class.

Example:

```
public class Event
{
    // Other properties...

    //Replace UnitId property with this property
    public Unit Unit {get;set;}

}
```

1. Bind to the `Description` property of the `Unit` class.

Example: `<DataGridTextColumn Header="Unit" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Unit.Description}"/>`

Comment: I wanted to avoid doing this, but I actually think this is probably the best route to go. I'll have to change my data access layer to return the full Unit object rather than just it's Id.